# In Hyperledger Fabric, how do I join a channel if I cannot use the peer channel fetch command?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I want to be able to have my peer join a channel (mychannel in this case). This specific peer does not have the `mychannel.block` file on its filesystem.

What I then tried was to use `peer channel fetch 0 -c mychannel`. I then get the following error:

```
2019-01-15 08:11:18.948 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP ZafitMSP validating identity
2019-01-15 08:11:18.949 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 037 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-15 08:11:18.949 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 parsed scheme: ""
2019-01-15 08:11:18.949 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 039 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-01-15 08:11:18.949 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03a ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer1.zafit.example.com:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-01-15 08:11:18.949 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-01-15 08:11:18.950 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4202b78d0, CONNECTING
2019-01-15 08:11:18.952 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03d pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4202b78d0, READY
2019-01-15 08:11:18.953 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 03e Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-01-15 08:11:18.953 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 03f Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-15 08:11:18.953 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-15 08:11:18.953 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 041 Sign: plaintext: 0AF2060A1508051A0608A6ABF6E10522...1BB3248E4BFA12080A021A0012021A00
2019-01-15 08:11:18.953 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 042 Sign: digest: C8988576954088FD1A61D6D4FFA7A7280E52F10B2F2671693C260B54B09F3B89
2019-01-15 08:11:18.954 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 043 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
```

However, when I copy the `mychannel.block` file from another peer I am able to join `mychannel` successfully. The `peer channel fetch` command also works successfully after joining the channel.

To me this seems like a chicken and egg scenario, I need to join the channel as a peer, but I can't join because I need the genesis block. But I can't get the genesis block because I need to join the channel?

**So the question is what is the appropriate command to retrieve the genesis `mychannel.block` file?**

Comment: Did you remember to set the environment variables for the peer? CORE_PEER_ZZZZ

Comment: @emiliomarin yes, these are set correctly.

Comment: I use this command: peer channel fetch 0  -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -c mychannel but I think that the default orderer address would be localhost:7050 (not my case). Make sure the orderer is working properly.
All I can think of is the environment variables... Here's what I export:
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH, CORE_PEER_ID, CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH, CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID, CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS, CORE_PEER_ADDRESS, CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS, CORE_PEER_EVENTS_ADDRESS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add the orderer parameter `-o`. Additionally, since I was connecting with TLS, I needed to specify `--tls true` as well as specify the `--cafile`.

The full command is as follows:?

`peer channel fetch 0 -c mychannel -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `-o` (`--orderer`) flag and set it to an ordering service endpoint.  If you don't set this flag, then `peer channel fetch` tries to get the block from the peer (which obviously does not have it).  You could also specific a different `--peer.address / CORE_PEER_ADDRESS` when running without `-o` to get the config block from a different peer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
peer channel fetch 0 -c mychannel
```

Note: You don't need to fetch channel in order to join channel
create channel will give .block file as a token of success.

join channel will make use of this inorder to complete the joining process

In case you miss .block then you need fetch command

Note: for latest fetch commands

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchannel.html

peer channel join -b channel.block --tls --cafile /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt

when you try to join a cahnnel you must contact the orderer to get config information that's why you will mention -o orderer_name in order to know about orderer by CLI